# Chart.js with Django - Using REST

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, chart.js

Using Django rest frame work i have my query set-up and pulling my data to a url like below. I'm trying to get the data in to chart.js. I can manage to get it to the console or plot the first result, but no further any assistance would be greatly appreciated

```
 "comp_history_data": [
        [
            "(2017, 01, 20)",
            256.0
        ],
        [
            "(2018, 01, 20)",
            456.0
        ],
        [
            "(2018, 02, 20)",
            568.0
        ],
        [
            "(2018, 03, 20)",
            683.0
        ]
    ],
```

Here is what i have in my HTML, works fine with dummy data, just not too sure how to plot with the data above

```
<script> 
var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
var defaultData = []
var labels = [];
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        labels = data.labels
        defaultData = data.comp_history_data.forEach(functoin(entry){
        console.log(entry)
        setChart()
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})
function setChart(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Computers',
            data: defaultData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
  }); 
} 


</script>
```

Small Edit: I can get one item onto the graph with the code below, so looks like the data is coming through OK, just need to separate

```
<script> 
    var endpoint = '/api/chart/data/'
    var defaultData = []
    var labels = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function(data){
            labels = data.labels
            defaultData = data.comp_history_data.forEach(functoin(entry){
            console.log(entry)
            setChart()
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
    function setChart(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx2, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Computers',
                data: defaultData[0],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
      }); 
    } 


    </script>
```

Any thoughts on how i use the data array i have with chart.js I would like the 0 the data to be along the bottom with the numbers plotted on the graph

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include `<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>` within your html file.

That might be all you need.  If not, this is a working function I have - I've not changed my variable names to match your's but I think it easy to understand.

```
        success : function(json) {

            // Add graph
            var chartLabels = json.categories.map(function(e) {
                return e.name;
            })
            var chartValues = json.values.map(function(e) {
                return e;
            })

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var data = {
                labels: chartLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    "label" : json.startRegulation[0].name,
                    "data" : chartValues,
                    "fill" : true,
                    "backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                    "borderColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                    "pointBackgroundColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                    "pointBorderColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBackgroundColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBorderColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)"
                }]
            }
            var options = {
                "elements":
                    {"line":{"tension":0,"borderWidth":3}
                    },
                scale  : {
                    ticks : {
                        min : 0,

                    }
                }
            }

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'radar',
                data: data,
                options : options,
            });
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help, got the HTML line in, i get the graph show just no data. I'm not too sure i understand whats append here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
defaultData = data.comp_history_data.forEach(functoin(entry){
```

to :

```
defaultData = data.comp_history_data.forEach(function(entry)){
```

Also, read the usage of template filters (Django) maybe you will find them helpful.

For instance, from your views.py file send data :

```
def MyView(request):
    comp_history_data: ['1', '2', '3']
    return render(request, 'chart.html', {'comp_history_data':comp_history_data})
```

and then in your HTML file print the vars :

```
{% for var in comp_history_data %}
{{ var }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an error in your success function, as below

```
defaultData = data.comp_history_data.forEach(functoin(entry){
```

to:

```
defaultData = data.comp_history_data.forEach(function(entry){
```